# Is there an R function to turn xyz data into an interpolated raster grid?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data frame containing xyz data.

```
df <- data.frame("X" = c(1:10), "Y" = c(3,6,1,7,8,9,4,2,10,5), "Z" = rnorm(10, 5))
```

I want to turn this data into a matrix grid. For the spaces in the grid where there are no values I would like to interpolate between the nearest data points to get a value. Then I want to take this data and plot it up using the `filled.contour()` function (e.g., `filled.contour(volcano)` ). How can I do this with R?

Comment: That's a _really_ sparse grid to impute or interpolate data, and it isn't clear to me that it's a monotonic/linear relationship in any direction. You might need to figure out what makes sense mathematically before you dive too much into how to do it in a language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a SpatRaster like this

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(df, type="xyz")
r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0.5, 10.5, 0.5, 10.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. :  
#source(s)   : memory
#name        :        Z 
#min value   : 4.603112 
#max value   : 6.553837
```

And then use inverse-distance-weighting (or another approach, see `?terra::interpolate`) to fill the gaps

```
x <- interpIDW(r, as.points(r), "Z", radius=10)
# or 
# x <- interpIDW(r, as.matrix(df), radius=10)
```

This algorithm is "exact" in the sense that the cells that had values in `r` (and `df`) have the same values in `x` (because the distance is zero). When using an inexact interpolation algorithm you could enforce that with

```
x <- cover(r, x)
```

You can directly plot `x`

```
plot(x)
lines(as.contour(x))

# or
contour(x, filled=TRUE)
```

Or you can transform `x` to a matrix and go with that:

```
m <- as.matrix(x, wide=TRUE)
```